# MongoDB: Is the data for same timestamps between oplogs of replicaset nodes and dumps are identical?

Tags: mongodb

Is the data for same timestamps ( i.e. pairs: [timestamp:number_of_operation] -- [operation] ) between oplogs:

- on primary server;
- on secondary server;
- in oplog, formed by mongodump (mongodump --oplog ...);

are identical?

Some my checks displays that are the same, but i can`t find this fact in official documentation.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The entries in the oplogs for a MongoDB replicaset are identical everywhere. The entries are created on the primary and then copied everywhere else - either via replication by reading from the local.oplog.rs collection or by being copied via mongodump with the `--oplog` option.

From the documentation:

> **Replica Set Oplog**
>
> The oplog (operations log) is a special capped collection that keeps a
>   rolling record of all operations that modify the data stored in your
>   databases. MongoDB applies database operations on the primary and then
>   records the operations on the primary’s oplog. The secondary members
>   then copy and apply these operations in an asynchronous process. All
>   replica set members contain a copy of the oplog, in the local.oplog.rs
>   collection, which allows them to maintain the current state of the
>   database.

Keep in mind that each entry may be copied a few times, if your replicaset is chaining it's replication, from primary to secondary to secondary for example. In each case however it's an identical copy of what came from the primary. The entries are created there and not updated.

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/replica-set-oplog/

Comment: So, secondary never changes <timestamp:op> field in oplog for any/some operations copied from primary? Am i right?

Comment: The secondary never makes change to the oplog data at all. It copies it, reads it and deletes from it but never changes it.